# High training and testing accuracy when training a binary classification model

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, svm, random-forest

I have a dataset where I split the train/test set to 66%/33%. I noticed my training accuracy is very high (in the 99s) regardless of which classification model algorithm. I also noticed while making predictions on the testing set. I get a testing accuracy score ranging from 97% -99%. This seems relatively high.

My question is this model overfitting or just the nature of the predictors give a clear cut on whether the classification is 1 or 0?

Also I want to note I have 15 predictor features. There are approximately 6-7 features that are important where as the latter ones have less importance. Should those still be included even though they don't provide as much importance as the top 6-7 features? My training set contains around 800 records that are classified as '1' and around 1400 classified as '0'. I did a random sample so that the classifications of 1 and 0 are balanced.

Comment: What are you modelling?  A high accuracy like that is suspicious, but some context could help clarify

Comment: trying to match company names with company names. i have features that consist of: name matched (1 or 0), fuzzy match (between 0 and 1), address match (1 or 0), domain match (1 or 0) and also included some edit distance algorithms such as jaro-winkler, damerau levenshtein, hamming, and jaccard distance. End goal is to see whether my predictions can predict whether it is a correct match or not

Comment: What's your definition of overfitting? Does this observation satisfy that definition? Why or why not?

Comment: At first I thought it could be a situation of overfitting due to the high training score. Then I also got a high testing accuracy which removed my doubt on overfitting. However, I feel a bit of skeptical due to how well it is performing. Could it just possible the nature of this problem and it just the model just predicts well for this certain type of problem?